# How can I allow profiles to transfer accounts but not cases?

Tags: permissions, sharing

I have to requirement that a subset of the Sales Users be able to change the ownership of Accounts even if they are not the Owner, but not be able to transfer ownership of Cases, unless they are the actual Case owner. In other words, they should be able to transfer ownership of any Account whether they're the Owner or not, but not transfer ownership of other User's Cases. They'll also need to be able to transfer their own Cases to other Users.

This requirement only applies to single Accounts. Mass transfers are not needed. The users have create/read/edit rights on Accounts and Cases.

The permission [Transfer Record](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=data_about_transfer.htm&language=en_US) allows the transfer of Accounts AND Cases. For Cases, the separate permission `Transfer Cases` exists, but if you have the `Transfer Record` permission, you don't need the `Transfer Case` permission.

Can anyone think of a solution to this?

Answer (score 2):

In Salesforce we would use what is called a Sharing Model

The sharing model defines how record-level privileges are granted to users who do not own the record. Configuring the sharing model is a two-part process. Organisation-wide default are used to establish the most restrictive level of access for each object. Sharing reasons override the default to grant access to individual records.

Every object that allows record ownership has an organisation wide default setting dictating how records are shared between the owner and other users. The setting can be Private, Public Read-Only, Public Read/Write, Controlled by Parent. To configure organisation wide defaults Setup -> Security Controls -> Sharing Settings.

**Private** : Records belong to the owner and only the owner. With the exception of the data administration-level privileges View All and Modify All, records are accessible only to their owners.

Sharing reasons override the organisation wide defaults to allow individual records to be shared between groups of users. The groups can be roles or public groups. Sharing between roles results in asymmetric privileges. Users in subordinate roles do not receive any privileges of their superiors, but superiors receive all the privileges of their subordinates. There are four types of sharing reasons : Manual, Sharing Rules, Procedural and Delegated Administration.

So essentially we will have to set Private on the Account object under the Organisation wide defaults and set, as a Sharing Rules that only the type of Role that you are interested to have Read/Edit access to any Account record. The Role can be assigned to a user just like a Profile.

A link to a Youtube video that will explain better the use of the [Sharing Model](http://youtu.be/c1ccSXlVjXk)

Also for reference: [Understanding Sharing](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_bulk_sharing_understanding.htm)

Comment: I am not sure how this answer is related to my question. My question is about changing ownership of accounts and cases to which users already have access to. The sharing settings are already configured and work fine.

Comment: I`ve updated the answer on what Private means so you would have a better understanding. Based on your requirements, what you will want is to have Cases as Private in the Organisation-wide defaults settings so only the owner will have access to it and for Account you should set it to Private as well and have a sharing rule which gives Read/Write access to the specific Role. And that Role should be assigned to whoever needs to change or modify Account records.

Comment: I think you are still missing the point here: Account and Case are already private, and Sales can access all the cases and accounts that they need to access. The problem is not about access, but about changing ownership.

Comment: Not to be argumentative, but if your sharing settings were working fine, you wouldn't have posted this. Sharing is about permissions. Your issue is that your sharing model is overly "permissive". The two are related and not independent. I'd urge you to look at the reference rather than dismissing it. I'd also look at the [Security Implementation Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.securityImplGuide.meta/securityImplGuide/).

Answer (score 0):

One possibility you may want to consider is implementing [Criteria Based 
Sharing rules](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=security_sharing_cbs_about.htm&language=en_US). In this manner, you could potentially share Accounts without sharing Cases to those who need to have the permission to edit Ownership of Accounts. You'd then be able to grant the Transfer Case permission to those who need it without being overly permissive and having Sales people who can transfer both Accounts and Cases they don't own.